# Why is there a white area where my iOS Status Bar is supposed to be

Tags: ios, statusbar

I created a new view controller and connected it up in an existing storyboard. I can see the status bar on all the preceding screens, but not on this one. There is just a white bar where it should be. I'm not doing anything to hide the status bar!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but the base view of my view controller was not transparent. When I made the background color of the base view of the view controller transparent, I could see my status bar again.